# What is server address to send request for push notification on ios apn

Tags: ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for sending push notification using GCM I send requests to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` but for ios using apn I couldn't find server address to send notification data.

What is address for using apn?

Comment: You can send notifications to iOS through GCM so you can send to the same endpoint.

Comment: @ArthurThompson Yes finally I used GCM's APN and I did the same as you mention